# Pseudo element not visible when using overflow

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am trying to have a vertical bar inside an overflow div using the pseudo element `before`:

```
.comments:before {
  width: 3px;
  top: -20px;
  bottom: -20px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

The problem as you can see in the demo is that the vertical bar is only created in the visible part of the div. The expected result is the vertical bar in the entire div, even in the hidden part as well.

```css
.comments {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 200px;
}

.comment {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0 1em;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.comment-img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 33px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.comment-img img {
  display: block;
}

.comment-body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.comment .text {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
}

.comment .text p:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.comment .attribution {
  margin: 0.5em 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666;
}


/* Decoration */

.comments,
.comment {
  position: relative;
}

.comments:before,
.comment:before,
.comment .text:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 65px;
}

.comments:before {
  width: 3px;
  top: -20px;
  bottom: -20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.comment:before {
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: 16px 0 0 -6px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background: #ccc;
}

.comment:hover:before {
  background: orange;
}

.comment .text:before {
  top: 18px;
  left: 78px;
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #e5e5e5;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

​
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

<section class="comments">
  <article class="comment">
    <a class="comment-img" href="#non">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/444197466133385216/UA08zh-B.jpeg" alt="" width="50" height="50">
    </a>
    <div class="comment-body">
      <div class="text">
        <p>Hello, this is an example from me</p>
      </div>
      <p class="attribution">by <a href="#non">Besnik Hetemi</a> at 14:23pm, 4 Dec 2015</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="comment">
    <a class="comment-img" href="#non">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/444197466133385216/UA08zh-B.jpeg" alt="" width="50" height="50">
    </a>
    <div class="comment-body">
      <div class="text">
        <p>if you are interested for more about me visited my profile on social page</p>
        <p>To visit me you can click my name <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/besnik.hetemii">Besnik Hetemi</a> and send me frends request or send me a message in inbox</p>
      </div>
      <p class="attribution">by <a href="#non">Besnik Hetemi</a> at 14:23pm, 4 Dec 2015</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="comment">
    <a class="comment-img" href="#non">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/444197466133385216/UA08zh-B.jpeg" alt="" width="50" height="50">
    </a>
    <div class="comment-body">
      <div class="text">
        <p>if you are interested for more about me visited my profile on social page</p>
        <p>To visit me you can click my name <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/besnik.hetemii">Besnik Hetemi</a> and send me frends request or send me a message in inbox</p>
      </div>
      <p class="attribution">by <a href="#non">Besnik Hetemi</a> at 14:23pm, 4 Dec 2015</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="comment">
    <a class="comment-img" href="#non">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/444197466133385216/UA08zh-B.jpeg" alt="" width="50" height="50">
    </a>
    <div class="comment-body">
      <div class="text">
        <p>if you are interested for more about me visited my profile on social page</p>
        <p>To visit me you can click my name <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/besnik.hetemii">Besnik Hetemi</a> and send me frends request or send me a message in inbox</p>
      </div>
      <p class="attribution">by <a href="#non">Besnik Hetemi</a> at 14:23pm, 4 Dec 2015</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="comment">
    <a class="comment-img" href="#non">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/444197466133385216/UA08zh-B.jpeg" alt="" width="50" height="50">
    </a>
    <div class="comment-body">
      <div class="text">
        <p>if you are interested for more about me visited my profile on social page</p>
        <p>To visit me you can click my name <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/besnik.hetemii">Besnik Hetemi</a> and send me frends request or send me a message in inbox</p>
      </div>
      <p class="attribution">by <a href="#non">Besnik Hetemi</a> at 14:23pm, 4 Dec 2015</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="comment">
    <a class="comment-img" href="#non">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/444197466133385216/UA08zh-B.jpeg" alt="" width="50" height="50">
    </a>
    <div class="comment-body">
      <div class="text">
        <p>if you are interested for more about me visited my profile on social page</p>
        <p>To visit me you can click my name <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/besnik.hetemii">Besnik Hetemi</a> and send me frends request or send me a message in inbox</p>
      </div>
      <p class="attribution">by <a href="#non">Besnik Hetemi</a> at 14:23pm, 4 Dec 2015</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ln9oth60/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a `wrapper` element for the `comments` element and apply the vertical bar *pseudo element* on this element. Now you can make the height of the vertical bar and `comments` section equal by making the `wrapper` element a flexbox (the default `align-items: stretch` will make the heights equal).

See demo below (the changes are marked inline):

```css
.comments {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 200px;
}

.comment {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0 1em;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.comment-img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 33px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.comment-img img {
  display: block;
}

.comment-body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.comment .text {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
}

.comment .text p:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.comment .attribution {
  margin: 0.5em 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666;
}


/* Decoration */

.comments,
.comment {
  position: relative;
}

.comments:before,
.comment:before,
.comment .text:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 65px;
}

.wrapper {
  /* added */
  display: flex;
}


/* .comments:before changed to this */

.wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  width: 3px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: relative;
  left: 65px;
}

.comment:before {
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: 16px 0 0 -6px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background: #ccc;
}

.comment:hover:before {
  background: orange;
}

.comment .text:before {
  top: 18px;
  left: 78px;
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #e5e5e5;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<section class="wrapper"> <!-- <-- new wrapper container -->
  <section class="comments">
    <article class="comment">
      <a class="comment-img" href="#non">
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/444197466133385216/UA08zh-B.jpeg" alt="" width="50" height="50">
      </a>
      <div class="comment-body">
        <div class="text">
          <p>Hello, this is an example from me</p>
        </div>
        <p class="attribution">by <a href="#non">Besnik Hetemi</a> at 14:23pm, 4 Dec 2015</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article class="comment">
      <a class="comment-img" href="#non">
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/444197466133385216/UA08zh-B.jpeg" alt="" width="50" height="50">
      </a>
      <div class="comment-body">
        <div class="text">
          <p>if you are interested for more about me visited my profile on social page</p>
          <p>To visit me you can click my name <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/besnik.hetemii">Besnik Hetemi</a> and send me frends request or send me a message in inbox</p>
        </div>
        <p class="attribution">by <a href="#non">Besnik Hetemi</a> at 14:23pm, 4 Dec 2015</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article class="comment">
      <a class="comment-img" href="#non">
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/444197466133385216/UA08zh-B.jpeg" alt="" width="50" height="50">
      </a>
      <div class="comment-body">
        <div class="text">
          <p>if you are interested for more about me visited my profile on social page</p>
          <p>To visit me you can click my name <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/besnik.hetemii">Besnik Hetemi</a> and send me frends request or send me a message in inbox</p>
        </div>
        <p class="attribution">by <a href="#non">Besnik Hetemi</a> at 14:23pm, 4 Dec 2015</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article class="comment">
      <a class="comment-img" href="#non">
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/444197466133385216/UA08zh-B.jpeg" alt="" width="50" height="50">
      </a>
      <div class="comment-body">
        <div class="text">
          <p>if you are interested for more about me visited my profile on social page</p>
          <p>To visit me you can click my name <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/besnik.hetemii">Besnik Hetemi</a> and send me frends request or send me a message in inbox</p>
        </div>
        <p class="attribution">by <a href="#non">Besnik Hetemi</a> at 14:23pm, 4 Dec 2015</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article class="comment">
      <a class="comment-img" href="#non">
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/444197466133385216/UA08zh-B.jpeg" alt="" width="50" height="50">
      </a>
      <div class="comment-body">
        <div class="text">
          <p>if you are interested for more about me visited my profile on social page</p>
          <p>To visit me you can click my name <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/besnik.hetemii">Besnik Hetemi</a> and send me frends request or send me a message in inbox</p>
        </div>
        <p class="attribution">by <a href="#non">Besnik Hetemi</a> at 14:23pm, 4 Dec 2015</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article class="comment">
      <a class="comment-img" href="#non">
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/444197466133385216/UA08zh-B.jpeg" alt="" width="50" height="50">
      </a>
      <div class="comment-body">
        <div class="text">
          <p>if you are interested for more about me visited my profile on social page</p>
          <p>To visit me you can click my name <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/besnik.hetemii">Besnik Hetemi</a> and send me frends request or send me a message in inbox</p>
        </div>
        <p class="attribution">by <a href="#non">Besnik Hetemi</a> at 14:23pm, 4 Dec 2015</p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
</section> <!-- new wrapper container ends-->
```